# Set variable from alias in SQL query

Tags: php, sql, alias

I have a simple JOIN query:

```
$lstCheck = $dbWHMCS->query('SELECT * FROM tblmonitorports mp 
                            INNER JOIN tblmonitorhosts h ON h.hst_id = port_mon 
                            INNER JOIN tblhosting ho ON ho.id = h.hst_serverid
                            INNER JOIN tblclients cl ON cl.id = ho.userid');

while ($data = $lstCheck->fetch())
{
            $serveridx = $data['ho.id'];
            $clientid = $data['cl.id'];
}
```

My problem is that I have an "id" column in both the tblhosting and tblclients tables, so my variables both have the same id. I tried to set it using an alias in the example above (ho. and cl.) but it doesn't work. How can I do this in the example above?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? (a bit rusty on php details, but this should do it):

```
$lstCheck = $dbWHMCS->query('SELECT ho.id hid, cl.id cid FROM tblmonitorports mp 
                            INNER JOIN tblmonitorhosts h ON h.hst_id = port_mon 
                            INNER JOIN tblhosting ho ON ho.id = h.hst_serverid
                            INNER JOIN tblclients cl ON cl.id = ho.userid');

while ($data = $lstCheck->fetch())
{
            $serveridx = $data['hid'];
            $clientid = $data['cid'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mirko, this would most likely work however I am using * because I am using over 40 columns for the rest of the page!

Comment: I know this can be a pain, but it is generally best practice to include all columns anyway, regardless of how many there are. I also frankly don't have a better answer as while you can do things like ho.* to include all ho columns, I know of no way to alias a single column and include all columns too.

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting the records, with a wild card `*`, so you can't select the fields like that.

As per your query `h.hst_serverid` & `ho.userid` have the exact same value as you want. SO simply do this

```
while ($data = $lstCheck->fetch())
{
            $serveridx = $data['hst_serverid'];
            $clientid = $data['userid'];
}
```

However, selecting specific rows might sound better too

```
$lstCheck = $dbWHMCS->query('SELECT ho.id hid, cl.id cid, ....');

while ($data = $lstCheck->fetch())
{
            $serveridx = $data['hid'];
            $clientid = $data['cid'];
}
```